# Are these REs equivalent?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, compilers

I have to implement a compiler for a given language as part of an assignment.
The language is kept simple enough such that it can be fully expressed through REs.

My question lies with two of the REs provided:

> DIGIT := [0-9]?
>
> INTEGER_LITERAL := DIGIT DIGIT*

When I saw the RE for `INTEGER_LITERAL` I sort of thought to myself:

> "Well that's just DIGIT+"

Am I right to think so?

Comment: I realised that some texts use a different definition for the symbols "+" and "\*". Here, they mean *one or more* and *zero or more* respectively.

Comment: With the definitions given, indeed AA* is equivalent to A+.

Comment: Note that the definition of DIGIT should be just [0-9]. Otherwise the empty string is also an integer literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any regular expression satisfies $r^+ = rr^* = r^*r$. In fact, one often *defines* $r^+$ using one of these formulas, usually $r^+ := rr^*$.